# Routing user to error page from the ErrorHandler's handleError function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-router

I have created a class `GlobalErrorHandler` that extends `ErrorHandler` and I want to route users to an error page from within the `handleError` function.

The goal is to avoid having to route the user to error every time I throw a fatal error which leaves room for development errors and missed usecases where the user will be left on offending the page with no messaging.

`GlobalErrorHandler` class itself is working great.

Here I am overriding the default provider
`app.module.js`

```
providers: [
    ...
    {
        provide: ErrorHandler,
        useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
    }
],
```

I 1st tried to inject Router like you would anything else.  Since Router depends on the ErrorHandler that was shutdown quickly.  So I tried the below based on some internet searching

`error.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor(
    private logglyService:LogglyLoggerService,
    private inj: Injector
    // private router: Router // Clearly doesn't work
  ) {
    super();
  }

  handleError(error) {
    let router = this.inj.get(Router)
    router.navigate(['error'], { skipLocationChange: true, replaceUrl: false })
        .then(data => console.log('THEN', data)) // Route was success
        .catch(data => console.log('catch', data));
    this.logglyService.log(error);
  }
}
```

I have injected the `Injector` service and using it to get `Router`.  This "works".  Elsewhere in the project I make something throw an error and test it.

It redirect the user to error page, but the offending page is still below it.

Looks like this

```
 ___________________________________
|                                   |
|                                   |
|       Orignal Page                |
|                                   |
|       /Error button\              |
|                                   |
 ___________________________________
```

Then you click the button and get this

```
 ___________________________________
|                                   |
|                                   |
|       You found an error          |
|                                   |
|                                   |
 ___________________________________
|                                   |
|                                   |
|       Original Page               |
|                                   |
|       /Error button\              |
|                                   |
 ___________________________________
```

Its as if the `Router` that `GlobalErrorHandler` gets is the router for something else than the `Router` I get when I inject it else where in my project

Note: the Original page no longer functions.

Note: the `.then` and `.catch` were just added to see if the `.navigate` call was failing.  Its not.

Comment: Would you please provide us with routing.module.ts and where you use the error component on the app.

Comment: Did you try using useFactory instead of useClass and give it Router as deps ?

Comment: @Nour I don't have a routing.module.ts.  I'm just using the built in routing.  As for my routes, they are pretty typical,

    `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },`

    `{ path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },`

    `{ path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }`

Comment: @Gilsdav,  I tried replacing `useClass` with `useFactory` in the `app.module.js` and uncommented injection of the router in `error.ts`.  I still get the cyclic dependency error

Comment: @MindlessRouse Is-it possible to know the type of error you are dispatching ?

Comment: On the button click, I'm just throwing a new error. `throw new Error('Failed')`